# "File As" Expression in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have built a query that has expression to create a "File As" field.  For the query, I have fields for ParticipantFName, ParticipantLName (combined in "Owner" field) and BusinessName.  In the "File As" field, if the "Owner" field is empty, it will add the BusinessName (so it will either show the owner or the business, whichever is filled in) and it works great.  Now I'm being asked to add a field for TribeName.

What would the expression be if the owner is empty and the business name is empty to show the tribe name?  The expression I have now is

```
File As: Nz([Owner],[BusinessName])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider nesting the `NZ()` function:

```
File As: Nz([Owner], Nz([BusinessName], [TribeName]))
```

Alternatively, use [IIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3):

```
File As: IIF([Owner] IS NOT NULL, [OWNER], 
             IIF([BusinessName] IS NOT NULL, [BusinessName], 
                 IIF([TribeName] IS NOT NULL, [TribeName], NULL)))
```